# Crackling static in speakers, Sony Audiophile, Ford Focus 2005

Tags: ford, focus, audio

I have a Ford Focus 2005 ZX4 ST, that has Sony Audiophile speakers, which come packaged by default with that particular model.

- I have not modified them since buying the car used, and everything looks standard AFAICT.
- The two front speakers embedded in the driver and passenger doors randomly will crackle (imagine radio static with the sound going in and out, or like when you don't have an audio cord fully plugged in for computer speakers)
- When I place my hand over the speaker cover, it feels "static-y" (hairs on my hair will stand up, etc).

> What are some likely causes of the crackling, and how can I go about
>   troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: Are they aftermarket speakers? Are they hooked up to an amp? You say the crackle is random, but is it always at a higher volume?

Comment: @Tim I added some clarification, hopefully some of that helps - I'm not sure about the amp (extremely ignorant about car audio equipment) - it has a subwoofer in the trunk if that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

For troubleshooting, here are some things to try:

Adjust the balance on your stereo to see if you can hear the crackling more to the left or the right, or both. Similarly you can adjust the fade to front / rear to see if the crackling is more in the front or the back. Once you have determined which speaker is causing the crackling, turn the stereo volume down low.  If it still crackles at low volume, you may have a blown speaker.

You can also take off the door panel and physically inspect the speaker.  Make sure the cone does not have any cracks or tears in it. If there are any tears or cracks, the speaker is blown and needs to be replaced.

Also inspect the speaker connections.  Make sure they are secure and there are no signs of corrosion.

That would be where I would start.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response. I'll try to do that and report back what I find.

Comment: @ClintonFreeman did you get this resolved?